# How to access the human-readable name using get_FOO_display

Tags: python, django, otree

Hello I have the next code to show to my participants the text of the response that the gave me in a anterior session.

```
    J11 = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[
            [-2, 'Muy moralmente inapropiado'],
            [-1, 'Moralmente inapropiado'],
            [0, 'No aplica'],
            [1, 'Moralmente apropiado'],
            [2, 'Muy moralmente apropiado'],
        ],
        widget=widgets.RadioSelect
    )
    TJ11 = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=J11)
```

When I try to prove this code I get the next error:

```
File "C:\Users\diese\iat\incentivos\models.py", line 140, in <module>
 class Player(BasePlayer):
File "C:\Users\diese\iat\incentivos\models.py", line 216, in Player
 TJ11 = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=J11)
File "c:\users\diese\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\otree\db\models.py",   line 386, in __init__super().__init__(max_length=max_length, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\diese\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\otree\db\models.py", line 217, in __init__
fix_choices_arg(kwargs)
File "c:\users\diese\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\otree\db\models.py",   line 195, in fix_choices_arg
choices = expand_choice_tuples(choices)
File "c:\users\diese\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- packages\otree\common_internal.py", line 118, in expand_choice_tuples
if not isinstance(choices[0], (list, tuple)):
TypeError: 'IntegerField' object is not subscriptable
```

What Can I do? Someone has experienced the same ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is coming from the field `TJ11` that has not been shared in your question

Comment: Ohh I am sorry, there is the same sintax for the TJ11 item

Comment: `choices=J12` - `J12` is a field and not an iterable of choices. Do you want 2 fields with the same choices?

Comment: Yes, there is Likert scale so I need a lot of fields with the same choices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define choices before you define your field and then assign those choices to the field afterwards . This allows you to assign those choices to multiple fields:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    (-2, 'Muy moralmente inapropiado'),
    (-1, 'Moralmente inapropiado'),
    (0, 'No aplica'),
    (1, 'Moralmente apropiado'),
    (2, 'Muy moralmente apropiado'),
)
J11 = models.IntegerField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
TJ12 = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

Comment: In that way I shouldn't get this error 'IntegerField' object is not subscriptable? I am trying to call the text in the choice to other template of my app

Comment: No, because you wouldn't be passing an IntegerField as the value for choices to another field

Comment: One last question how should I call this value in my template? In the next form: player.get_J12_display() ?

Comment: Yeah that's a fine way of getting the selected value of the field

Comment: I get the next error : File "C:\Users\diese\iat\incentivos\models.py", line 220
    J11 = models.IntegerField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: There isn't any syntax error in that code, can you share the entire model code in your question?

Comment: The code is very long, more or less 1000 lines, should i post it ?

Comment: Maybe, try copying the code again, maybe you missed something?

Comment: Okey, I changed it, and this see the same.